# Can no longer run rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something happened and I can no longer run rviz.  I get the following when I try to run it:

$ rosrun rviz rviz

find: invalid predicate `-L'

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rviz below /opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz

find: invalid predicate `-H'

```
$ ls -l /opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz/bin
total 4236
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root      1207114 Feb  6 14:22 image_view
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       763727 Feb  6 14:22 marker_test
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root      1115605 Feb  6 14:22 rviz
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       398799 Feb  6 14:22 send_grid_cells
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       324022 Feb  6 14:22 send_images
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       515215 Feb  6 14:22 send_lots_of_points
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30142/can-no-longer-run-rviz/) by [Dallas Goecker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1654/dallas-goecker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dallas Goecker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1654/dallas-goecker/) on 2012-03-21**:
I am able to run rviz directly by running:  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization/rviz/bin/rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your version of find changed.  -L and -H are top level options on my man page for find.

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)
```

from the man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [path...] [expression]
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0